# graphics.h -lbgi not found

Tags: c, compiler-errors, bgi

We are using Code::Blocks (version 20.03) to learn programming in C. For homework we shall implement with the grahics.h library. But installing this library comes along very hard for me.

I already downloaded the needed files from https://winbgim.codecutter.org/, changed the code in graphics.h in line 302 from "right" to "top", https://winbgim.codecutter.org/. Then I put the files in to the supposedly right folders (according to this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEkAj-xVTKQ).

After a long run I fixed the error "Cannot open include file: 'graphics.h': No such file or directory" by adding the directories of all added files under Settings --> Compiler --> Search directories --> Compiler and using a .cpp-file.

Now I wanted to test with the following small programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>

int main()
{
    initwindow( 700, 700, "MY First Program");
    circle(200, 200, 150);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I get the error:
"cannot find -lbgi
error: ld returned 1 exit status"

I already tried for six hours to find a solution but I cannot find one which helps.

- `#include "graphics.h"` does not make a difference

It would be great if someone knows a solution and would be so kind and share it with me. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add the directory with `libbgi.a` to linker search directories.

Comment: Unrelated note: the libraries from codecutter date back to 2005 and target GCC 3 (Yes GCC 3. Yes the cool kids are all using GCC11) and Windows XP. The BGI API is even older than that, dating back to the 1980s. The world has changed a lot since then. You can do absolutely everything right and it still might not work on modern PC hardware with a modern OS and a modern compiler. If you have to do this for school, give them what they want and pass the class, but you should supplement your education with modern materials to smooth your entry into industry.

Comment: And shame on the school. Software development is a fast paced industry, and teaching it with twenty-and-forty-year-old tools is a disservice to the students. If you're doing this for personal enlightenment, there are better things you can spend your time learning. Eg. [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) and [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/). If you are still interested in BGI, [Here's a link to SDL -BGI](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/), the BGI API implemented atop SDL and usable on modern hardware and Operating Systems.

Comment: graphics.h is a DOS header file.   Not something you want to use with windows or linux

Answer (score 0):

Compiler  must be 32bit not 64 bit watch this video to understand

https://youtu.be/VEkAj-xVTKQ